# USB port stop working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse, peripherals

Sometimes (maybe 1-2 times in a week) if I disconnect my mouse from the computer (desktop, just build it 1 months ago) by pulling it out from usb port and then connect it back my mouse will not work (I can't move my cursor and the LED beneath the mouse doesn't light up).

My keyboard would still be working, but if I pull out and then connect back the keyboard to a usb port, it will stop working, too. If I connect my phone (Android) to usb port it will show that phone is charging, but I can't open the phone storage on my computer (it doesn't popup a message asking if I want to use usb connection to transfer files like it usually does). I tried to connect to usb port on the back of my PC - doesn't work.

Also, when this happens if I click start menu and reboot the system, it doesn't reboot: the screen just goes black and the computer is still running, nothing happens.

I'm using Windows 10. Do you know why my usb would sometimes stop working and how to fix this or how to identify what is the cause of this?

Comment: This may be a USB driver issue or USB port hardware issue itself. To check the driver issue you need to just to Device Manager and check if USB host drivers are in place and there no yellow signs on them. Hardware issue can be resolved only by repairing the motherboard.

Comment: Did you try to use windows built-in troubleshooter for keyboard and mouse? 
Normally, for the keyboard or mouse not responding issue, it is always suggested to check from driver first, then check event logs when issue occurrence to figure out if any errors have been recorded.
Moreover, check for update in case there is any known issue have been fixed by windows monthly update or patches.